# c++ non-template class friends to a member of template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I am new using template. As title, I have a non-template classes (Obj and ObjBase) and a template class PItem. I want to let PITem::RefValue() accesses private members in Obj.

I thought below would work:

> ```
>    template<class T>
>    friend int PItem<T>::getValue();
> ```

It doesn't:

> error C2248: 'Obj::getValue': cannot access private member declared in class 'Obj'
>
> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int PItem::getValue(void)' being compiled

Compiler complaints:

> ```
>    if (ptr) return ptr->getValue();
> ```

```
class ObjBase
{
public:
    ObjBase() {}
    ~ObjBase(){}
protected:
    int  value{0};
};

class Obj : public ObjBase
{
    template<class T>
    class PItem;

    template<class T>
    friend int PItem<T>::getValue();

public:
    Obj(int i) { value = i; };
    ~Obj() {};

private:
    int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class PItem
{
public:
    PItem(T* t) { ptr = t; }
    ~PItem() {}
    int getValue() {
        if (ptr) return ptr->getValue();
        return -1;
    }
    T* ptr;
};
```

Comment: where's the code where you instantiate the template and call its function?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: You shouldn't declare another class's function a `friend` before its declaration, move the `class PItem` body before the `Obj` class's body...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring a nested class template `PItem` inside `Obj`, then the `friend` declaration refers to it, not the one defined in globle scope.

You should remove the nested class template declaration, and move the definition of `PItem` before the definition of `Obj`; because the `friend` declaration requires `PItem` to be complete type.

```
template<typename T>
class PItem
{
public:
    PItem(T* t) { ptr = t; }
    ~PItem() {}
    int getValue() {
        if (ptr) return ptr->getValue();
        return -1;
    }
    T* ptr;
};

class Obj : public ObjBase
{

    template<class T>
    friend int PItem<T>::getValue();

public:
    Obj(int i) { value = i; };
    ~Obj() {};

private:
    int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5FB2gBSUYaU4HgJx)

Comment: @KelvinLai, please accept the answer if it solves your problem.